# How to copy element from one div to another div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, copy

How can I copy an element after I click on one `<div>` in Master, so that it will appear in Creation immediately?

'Master' div looks like this:

```
  <div id="master" class="master">

        <p id="feedback">
            <span>You've selected:</span> <span id="select-result">none</span>.
        </p>


        <div class="frame" style="align-content: center">
            <div class="portlet portlet-count firstTab" id="1">
                <div class="portlet-header">First</div>
                <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

            </div>
            <div class="portlet portlet-count firstTab" id="2">
                <div class="portlet-header">Second</div>
                <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

            </div>

            <div class="portlet portlet-count firstTab" id="3">
                <div class="portlet-header">Third</div>
                <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

'Creation' div looks like this:

```
   <div id="creation">
        <p id="newFeedback">
            <span>You've selected:</span> <span id="select-result-2">none</span>.
        </p>

        <div class="newFrame" style="align-content: center">
            <div class="portlet portlet-count secondTab" id="11">

            </div>
        </div>
```

jQuery

```
 $(function () {
    $(".frame").selectable({
        stop: function () {
            var result = $("#select-result").empty();
            var newResult = $("#select-result-2").empty();
            var add = $("#newExam").empty();
            var count = 0;
            var $this = $(this);

            $(".ui-selected", this).each(function () {

                if (this.id > 0) {
                    result.append(this.id + " ");
                    newResult.append(this.id + " ");
                    count = count + 1;

                    if ($this.hasClass("firstTab")) {
                        $this.addClass("secondTab").prependTo("#creation");
                    } else {
                        $this.addClass("firstTab").prependTo("#master");
                    }
                }
            });
            add.append(count);
        }
 });
});
```

Comment: when you copy what should happen to the existing element in `newFrame`.. also what if clicked multiple times in a item

Comment: Also share us what you have already tried

Comment: Something new will add on the top in Creation, so it means newFrame will go down but still exist. However, it has to be clicked once per item. @ArunPJohny

Comment: so whenever a an item a clicked a new `newFrame` has to be created and added after the `#creation .newFeedback` element`

Comment: why are you using selectable

Comment: Oh I see, I changed to onclick follow an answer of @thi tran . Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a simple click handler like

```js
$('.frame .portlet').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    $error;
  if ($this.hasClass('added')) {
    $error = $this.next('.clone-error');
    if (!$error.length) {
      $error = $('<span />', {
        'class': 'clone-error',
        text: 'Alread added'
      }).insertAfter(this);
    }
    $error.stop().show().delay(500).hide(1);
  } else {
    $this.addClass('added').clone().appendTo('#creation .newFrame');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="master" class="master">

  <p id="feedback">
    <span>You've selected:</span>  <span id="select-result">none</span>.
  </p>


  <div class="frame" style="align-content: center">
    <div class="portlet portlet-count firstTab" data-id="1">
      <div class="portlet-header">First</div>
      <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>

    <div class="portlet portlet-count firstTab" data-id="2">
      <div class="portlet-header">Second</div>
      <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>

    <div class="portlet portlet-count firstTab" data-id="3">
      <div class="portlet-header">Third</div>
      <div class="portlet-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>


<div id="creation">
  <p id="newFeedback">
    <span>You've selected:</span>  <span id="select-result-2">none</span>.
  </p>

  <div class="newFrame" style="align-content: center">
    <div class="portlet portlet-count secondTab" data-id="11">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! what if clicked multiple times then it show alert message on the right hand side of div?

Comment: @PloyyPpositive whether an alert statement will be enough?

Comment: Hi @ArunPJohny , when I clicked on minus/plus icon at right hand-side for expand/collapse div then this div was selected. What should I do?

Comment: this is portlet:


`$(".portlet")
          .addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
          .find(".portlet-header")
            .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
            .prepend("<span class='ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick portlet-toggle'></span>");`

Answer (score 0):

See my example below

```js
function copyMe(element) {
    element = $(element).clone(); //copy
    //element = $(element); //if move
    element.appendTo($('#creation'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="copyMe(this);">
    Div 1
</div>
<div onclick="copyMe(this);">
    Div 2
</div>
<div onclick="copyMe(this);">
    Div 3
</div>
<div id="creation">
</div>
```